# Form data source edit method on a view - AX 2009

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to add a edit method to my grid from my data source in the form. I have the following code for the edit method:

```
edit boolean markLine(
boolean             set,
Datasource          _datasource,
boolean             _mark
)
{
    if (set)
    {
        if (!_mark)
        {
            if (selectedLines.exists(_datasource.RecId))
            {
                selectedLines.remove(_datasource.RecId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            selectedLines.insert(_datasource.RecId,_datasource.recVersion);
        }
    }

    return selectedLines.exists(_datasource.RecId);
}
```

I then drag that into a grid which has the datasource specified in it and contains other fields from that datasource. Yet, when I try to use it in the grid, it is not possible to check the box.

I am using a view for my data source, not a table. I am not sure if this is the reason for it or if there is something else that is the problem. Any idea what the problem could be here?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

AllowEdit on the data source is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I checked around some more and found the following in the AX documentation about views

> Views are read-only. The data fields and tables that a view uses cannot be updated from that view.

Therefore, edit methods will not work because views cannot be edited in the first place.

## Edit

A workaround for this is to override the mouseDblClick method in the grid. Add the following code lines after the super():

```
Datasource_ds.selectedLines(true, Datasource, !selectedLines.exists(Datasource.RecId));
Datasource_ds.refresh();
```

Then when the user double clicks a method, it is selected.